# Tornado security issue

Tags: python, security, cookies, tornado

I am new to Tornado, the python framework. I came across that, It does not support session and authentication is done using secure cookies.

But how secure really it is?

I did this simple thing to test it. I logged in to the application, Exported the cookies using [EditThisCookie](http://www.editthiscookie.com/) and then I logged out. After that, I simply imported the cookie and now I am logged into the application.

I tried this with 2 applications that claim to have done using tornado and got same result on both the occasions.

Is this something expected? Or is there a better way to secure the tornado applications?

I tried with an [example](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/security.html) from the tornado website and found the same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's expected behavior. The secure cookie is a token the browser keeps to prove it's logged in. If you move the cookie from the browser to your hard drive, then reimport it to the browser, the browser can once again prove to the Tornado application that it's logged in.

Comment: So Tornado doesn't invalidate the cookie when the user logs out?

Comment: The standard behavior for Tornado (and for the great majority of web frameworks) is that when the user logs out, Tornado tells the *browser* to clear its cookie. See [clear_cookie](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/72e8695089833483c1352073679b4cffe3d47232/tornado/web.py#L570-L570). In the original question, @dev_avatar tells their browser to reload the cookie, so it's once again logged in. That's typically how cookie authentication works.